# How is it possible to pass an Iron Worker payload (ie params) to the CasperJS binary?

Tags: ruby, casperjs, args, payload, ironworker

Iron Worker is a great tool, however there is still some holes in its documentation...

I've successfully set up a worker using CasperJS, called by the Iron Worker ruby gem. But when the worker is called with params by the gem (passing a "payload" option), it is impossible to retrieve them in the js script.

An article is available on this topic but only for PhantomJS : http://giuseppeaiello.com/post/56318356914/phantomjs-ironworker

And trying to print all options ands args with native CasperJS methods doesn't output anything... http://casperjs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cli.html

Any ideas on how to make this work ?